# How to use built-in PHP-FPM in OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, php, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to know how php-fpm included in Mountain Lion (v10.8.5) can be used (eg. with NGINX).

I am afraid that some configuration might be needed before it is actually used.

NOTE: I know how to install nginx and configure it to use php in fastcgi mode. Actually I will be installing nginx from macports.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but use something like this:

`php-fpm --fpm-config /path/to/your/conf/file/php-fpm.conf -D`

The -D will force it to run in the background as a daemon, or

`php-fpm --fpm-config /path/to/your/conf/file/php-fpm.conf -F`

The -F will force it to stay in the foreground

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend you to install nginx from homebrew instead of macports.
Macports will pull and install all nginx's dependencies into its own environment while homebrew's nginx will use mac's native.
Thus using homebrew will probably make it easier to use and configure macosx's native php.

Comment: You did not mention anything about my main question (HOW TO USE BUILT-IN PHP-FPM).